# Font Awesome icons appear broken

Tags: fonts, font-awesome

Having issues with this one site (https://www.datacoral.com/font-awesome-test/) where no matter what, the Font Awesome icons always appear broken. The fonts are hosted locally and the error I get in Console is:

> The resource at “https://www.stacksite.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/fonts/fontawesome/webfonts/fa-solid-900.woff2” preloaded with link preload was not used within a few seconds. Make sure all attributes of the preload tag are set correctly.

That's really odd. In the header.php file (it's a WordPress site) I use this in the head:

```
    <link async rel="preload" href="/wp-content/themes/mytheme/fonts/fontawesome/webfonts/fa-solid-900.woff2" as="font" type="font/woff2" crossorigin>
```

Any idea why it's always broken?

Comment: Did you change anything after posting this question? I'm seeing a similar msg - but related to `animations.css` (which cames after `fa-solid-900`).   (I'm using Chrome87)

Comment: No, nothing. Why are you seeing the icons? Because I'm still not.

What happened with you and animations.css?

Comment: No, I didn't see the icons - but I only saw the msg as you - except that it was related to "animations.css" instead of "fa-solid..."    But I must admit I have no clue about `link async preload` - never needed it. When I had performance issues with a site, the best optimization for FA that I found was to use kits or subsets. Have you tried to just "simple" link-tags (w/o async&preload)?